# C# Datarow item DateTime format being ignored

Tags: c#, sql, .net, datetime

I am filling a DataTable using the results of a SQL SP. One of the columns is a DateTime type. When I try to format the DateTime value, it seems to be ignored.

For example:

```
foreach (DataRow row in sourceTable.Rows)
            {
                row["DateOfActivity"] = Convert.ToString(((DateTime)row["DateOfActivity"]).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"));
                Console.WriteLine(row["DateOfActivity"]);
            }
```

Results in:

```
2/17/2016 12:00:00 AM
```

How can I make sure the DateTime format is retained?

Comment: Why do you use `ToString()` and `Convert.ToString()` at the same time? Just use `String.Format("{0:yyyy-MM-dd}",(DateTime)row["DateOfActivity"])`

Comment: Whats the datatype of `row["DateOfActivity"]` I hope its string

Comment: Frankly I was just testing around with conversions to get the desired output so that's why it's converted to string twice. I ended up just doing the conversion later in the code, before it's written to the file, and that worked out well enough. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a databable, columns have specific types. When you assign back to `row["DateOfActivity"]`, you're assigning to a `DateTime` value. Writing that back to the console will give you the default `.ToString()` call.

The solution is to wait to format the output until you actually show it to the user. Get rid of the first line inside the loop completely and have the second line just look like this:

```
Console.WriteLine(row["DateOfActivity"].ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"));
```

Answer (score 0):

The type definition of the `row["DateOfActivity"]` column is not present in your question, however I am going to assume it is defined as a `DateTime` type.  This type definition stores the raw date/time value, without a format.

From MSDN:

> Internally, all DateTime values are represented as the number of ticks (the number of 100-nanosecond intervals) that have elapsed since 12:00:00 midnight, January 1, 0001. The actual DateTime value is independent of the way in which that value appears when displayed in a user interface element or when written to a file. The appearance of a DateTime value is the result of a formatting operation. Formatting is the process of converting a value to its string representation.
>
> Because the appearance of date and time values is dependent on such factors as culture, international standards, application requirements, and personal preference, the DateTime structure offers a great deal of flexibility in formatting date and time values through the overloads of its ToString method. The default DateTime.ToString() method returns the string representation of a date and time value using the current culture's short date and long time pattern. The following example uses the default DateTime.ToString() method to display the date and time using the short date and long time pattern for the en-US culture, the current culture on the computer on which the example was run.

You should be formatting the value of a `DateTime` type when you output it. If you want to store a formatted version of this value in your `DataTable` you will need to define the column as a string and then store the formatted value.

For more information see [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) link on the `DateTime` type.